# How to add Document with Custom ID to firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any chance to add a document to firestore collection with custom generated id, not the id generated by firestore engine?

Answer (score 384, accepted):

To use a custom  ID you need to use `.set`, rather than `.add`

This creates a document with the ID "LA":

```
db.collection("cities").doc("LA").set({
    name: "Los Angeles",
    state: "CA",
    country: "USA"
})
```

This is taken from the official docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)

Comment: What if I want to add to the doc `"LA"`?
This won't work: `.doc("LA").add({...})`
Please tell how can I do that.

Comment: `.add()` is equivalent to `.doc().set()`

Comment: If we want to add custome id then we have to use .doc().set() instead of add()

Comment: If you are using set() method to update document fields then be careful, it kills non-updated fields in the document. eg. I had 6 fields in a document and I updated only 4 fields then set() method removed 2 fields and their information from that document on firestore. Just sharing my experience. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh Just add `{ merge: true }` after your doc object to keep existing not updated fields.

Answer (score 32):

I'll just leave this here if anyone is looking for version 9.

This was taken from the docs.

```
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

// Add a new document in collection "cities" with "LA" as id
await setDoc(doc(db, "cities", "LA"), {
  name: "Los Angeles",
  state: "CA",
  country: "USA"
});
```

where `db` is:

```
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp)
```

Comment: thank you. It works great! here is the official link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9

Comment: thanks. appreciate the version 9 example

Answer (score 28):

In case if you are using angularfire,

```
class Component{
  constructor(private afs: AngularFireStore) {} // imported from @angular/fire/firestore

  addItem() {
    this.afs.collection('[your collection]').doc('[your ID]').set({your: "document"});
  }
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful here!

Answer (score 21):

To expand on the accepted answer, if you ever wanted your client to generate a random ID for the doc before pushing to Firestore (assuming the same `createId()` function exists outside of AngularFire2)

```
const newId = db.createId();
db.collection("cities").doc(newId).set({
    name: "Los Angeles",
    state: "CA",
    country: "USA"
})
```

This is useful for setting the ID as a reference field in another document, even before Firestore saves anything. If you don't need to use the saved object right away, this speeds up the process by not making you wait for the ID. The `set()` call is now asynchronous from the pipe you might be using in Angular

Notice I didn't put `id: newId` in the set object, because Firestore by default doesn't save ID as a field in the doc

Comment: outstanding, thank you for the hint on db.createId(), very useful

Comment: Just be careful that the operation may fail (for any reason), so don't assume that there is a saved object with that ID (or have some sort of fallback for such cases).

Comment: Very needed for angularfirestore!

Answer (score 6):

This is function that creates document with data and you can choose if you want to generate id yourself or automatically. If id is provided during the function callout then the document that will be created, is going to have the id that you provided.

Modular Firebase firestore 9.+

```
import { getFirestore, serverTimestamp, collection, doc, setDoc, addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore/lite'
async create(id = null, data) {
    const collectionRef = collection(getFirestore(), this.collectionPath)

    const dataToCreate = {
      ...data,
      createTimestamp: serverTimestamp(),
      updateTimestamp: serverTimestamp()
    }

    const createPromise =
      id === null || id === undefined
        ? // Create doc with generated id
          await addDoc(collectionRef, dataToCreate).then(d => d.id)
        : // Create doc with custom id
          await setDoc(doc(collectionRef, id), dataToCreate).then(() => id)

    const docId = await createPromise

    return {
      id: docId,
      ...data,
      createTimestamp: new Date(),
      updateTimestamp: new Date()
    }
  }
```

Same function for not modular Firebase firestore( < version 9)

```
import { firebase } from '@firebase/app'
async create(data, id = null) {
    const collectionRef = (await firestore()).collection(this.collectionPath)
    const serverTimestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

    const dataToCreate = {
      ...data,
      createTimestamp: serverTimestamp,
      updateTimestamp: serverTimestamp
    }

    const createPromise =
      id === null || id === undefined
        ? // Create doc with generated id
          collectionRef.add(dataToCreate).then(doc => doc.id)
        : // Create doc with custom id
          collectionRef
            .doc(id)
            .set(dataToCreate)
            .then(() => id)

    const docId = await createPromise

    return {
      id: docId,
      ...data,
      createTimestamp: new Date(),
      updateTimestamp: new Date()
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! this is the only answer that is still valid with the new modular Firebase @angular/firebase

Answer (score 5):

**You can do it this way**

```
// Inject AngularFirestore as dependency 
private angularFireStore: AngularFirestore // from from 'angularfire2/firestore'

// set user object to be added into the document
let user = {
  id: this.angularFireStore.createId(),
  name: 'new user'
  ...
}

// Then, finally add the created object to the firebase document
angularFireStore.collection('users').doc(user.id).set(user);
```

Answer (score 4):

**db.collection("users").document(mAuth.getUid()).set(user)**

Here, the name of the collection is `"users"` and the document name is the user's `UID`

**Here u need to use `set` not `add`**

```
private void storeData(String name, String email, String phone) {

    // Create a new user with a first and last name
    Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
    user.put("name", name);
    user.put("email", email);
    user.put("phone", phone);

    // Add a new document with a generated ID
    db.collection("users").document(mAuth.getUid()).set(user)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Toasty.success(context,"Register sucess",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Code Which is given First is for JavaScript This is for Android Studio (JAVA)

```
Map<String, Object> city = new HashMap<>();
city.put("name", "Los Angeles");
city.put("state", "CA");
city.put("country", "USA");
//Here LA is Document name for Assigning
db.collection("cities").document("LA")
    .set(city)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e);
        }
    });
```

To Set ID while adding data u have to Use **Set** Method

If This Code is Out-Dated Then Find the New Code [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#java)

Comment: `...First is for JavaScript`, do you mean `Java` ?

Comment: @phonixstudio it is Java Programming

Answer (score 1):

**Create new Document with ID**

```
  createDocumentWithId<T>(ref: string, document: T, docId: string) {
    return this.afs.collection(ref).doc<T>(docId).set(document);
  }
```

EX: this example with take email as ID for the document

```
this.fsService.createDocumentWithId('db/users', {}, credential.user.email);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add custom id not firestore generated then just do this:

val u:String=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid.toString()
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Shop Details").document(u).set(data)

//u is not in firestore it will create first and add data
//data is whatever you want to add in firestore

Answer (score 0):

**after researching a lot of time I got a solution for this by myself**

Actually, if we declare a ***String*** before and call that on hashmap it won't work.

So, the solution is:

```
 Map<String, Object> city = new HashMap<>();
                city.put("batch", "25");
                city.put("blood", ""+stuBlood.getText().toString());
                city.put("email", ""+stuEmail.getText().toString());
                city.put("facebook", ""+stuFacebook.getText().toString());
                city.put("gender", ""+stuGender.getText().toString());
                city.put("id", ""+stuID.getText().toString());
                city.put("image", ""+stuImage.getText().toString());
                city.put("location", ""+stuLocation.getText().toString());
                city.put("name", ""+stuName.getText().toString());
                city.put("phone", ""+stuPhone.getText().toString());
                city.put("whatsapp", ""+stuWhatsApp.getText().toString());
                city.put("telegram", ""+stuTelegram.getText().toString());
```

**Hope it's working now**

Answer (score 0):

**Adding document with custom ID**

```
  const onSubmit = useCallback(
    async ({ title, weekday }: WorkoutFormSchema) => {
      try {
        const customId = 'someId'

        const userWorkoutsCollectionRef = collection(
          database,
          'users',
          user.id,
          'workouts',
        )

        await setDoc(doc(database, userWorkoutsCollectionRef.path, customId), {
          title,
          weekday,
        })
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    },
    [],
  )
```