# How to use custom document id when creating documents in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having problems when creating users in the Authentication and Database parts of Firebase Firestore.

When users register, a new ID (UID in Authentication) will be generated, and another ID (document ID under users collection) will be generated. I'm trying to make both IDs in both the Authentication side and document ID the same when users create an account.

This is my code:

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override

                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            // Sign up success -> user data should store inside db
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override

                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {     //registered successfully

                                            user.put("email", email.getText().toString());
                                            user.put("password", password.getText().toString());

                                            //To write a user to the database
                                            mDatabase.collection("users").add(user)
                                                    // successfully add to db
                                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SUCCESS: Your account was created successfully! Please check your email for verification. User "
                                                                    + email.getText().toString() + " has been added to the database.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                                            Intent loginActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                                                            startActivity(loginActivity);
                                                        }
                                                    })

                                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error adding to DB", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                        }
                                                    });

                                        }
                                        // task was unsuccessful
                                        else {
                                            String fail = "FAIL: User failed to register: " + task.getException();
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), fail, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            Log.e("", fail);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else{
                                String fail = "FAIL: User failed to register: " + task.getException();
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), fail, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Log.e("", fail);
                            }
                        }
                    });`
```

I have tried setting the data using

```
FirebaseFirestore mDatabase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference usersRef = mDatabase.collection("users").document(currentUser);
String id = firebaseAuth.getUid();
usersRef.document(id).set(user);
```

to replace the parts of code in

```
Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
user.put("name", name.getText().toString());
user.put("email", email.getText().toString());
user.put("password", password.getText().toString());
```

but I got errors in the `.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>()` portion of codes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RArMu.png)

I'm new to Firebase, so any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: Please show what error you receive on OnSuccessListener

Comment: I've added an image above. It says Cannot resolve method

Comment: You should set the document on a DocumentReference, but in your screenshot, you're attempting to set that on an User object. Also- please try to attach code snippet in the post **as text** instead of image in future.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? How do I modify my codes?

Comment: `usersRef.document(id).set()`: here usersRef is not a document reference. You should create the document as `mDatabase.collection("users").document(currentUser.getUid()).set(...)`

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to know how to add documents with custom id using Firestore. I found this helpful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541270/how-to-add-document-with-custom-id-to-firestore)